# How to link within same page using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

How to link within the same using angular js ? In html we use  `<a href="#top">Top</a>` to go to element which have id="top".

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by doing the same using angular js? You should have the same HTML which should also work when using Angular JS. If you want to make it angular (which is pointless in this case) you can use the `ng-href` directive with exactly the same code as you already have.

Comment: let element = document.getElementById(#idOfTheTarget);
element.scrollIntoView(options);

#options will be an object = {
behavior : 'smooth;
}


Docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `target` attribute with value `"_self"` to the link:

```
<a href="#top" target="_self">Top</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$anchorScroll([hash])`

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using angular code you can try `$anchorScroll`.

Reference link.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Using JavaScript you can do same thing `scrollIntoView`.

Reference link.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Using jQuery you can do something like:

`$(window).scrollTop($('#id').offset().top);`